# Inserting two lists into sqllite db

Tags: python, sqlite

Working on a GUI app with Tkinter and I've collected information via a form into two lists. There is a reason behind why two lists, although there might be a better way.

So now I've got two lists, both contain data I need to enter into my database and each data point is a new row. For example, my gui is an equipment signout program.

So here is an example:

```
equipmentIdList = [123, 4568, 9876]
```

Note: *equipmentIdList*  is simply barcodes ids identifying the data in my db

```
assignedToList = [rob, chris, mike]
```

So barcode for equipment 123 is assigned to rob and is going into the database to mark it as being checked out. Same for chris and mike.

So where I'm at is how to get this into my database. I did try going to a dictionary but that doesn't seem to really solve my problem either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share the code you have worked so far with input and expected outputs.

Answer (score -1):

You may save your data in a table with 2 columns: person and equipment

```
(rob, 123)
(chris, 4568)
(mike, 9876)
```

First you should design and create your table in sqlite, then read document how to generate insert query into your database.